# createElement or appendChild not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put an img element in a span element that I created dynamically with JavaScript. The problem is that the span element isn't showing in the DOM tree. However, the img elements are shown on the page and are nested in the div element (#playfield) that is hard coded in my html code. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
var playfield = document.getElementById("playfield");
var indexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
shuffle(indexes);

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var vak1 = document.createElement("span");
    var kaart1 = document.createElement("img");
    var path1 = "img/kaart" + indexes[i] + ".png";
    var klasse1 = "img" + indexes[i];
    kaart1.setAttribute("src", "img/achterkant.png");
    kaart1.setAttribute("class", klasse1);
    kaart1.setAttribute("data-img", path1);
    kaart1.setAttribute("height", "150");
    kaart1.setAttribute("width", "150");
    kaart1.setAttribute("data-turned","false");
    playfield.appendChild(vak1.appendChild(kaart1));
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`playfield.appendChild(vak1.appendChild(kaart1));` Is the problem line. The result of `vak1.appendChild(kaart1)` is the appended child `kaart1` - do these 2 operation separately:

```
vak1.appendChild(kaart1);
playfield.appendChild(vak1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var playfield = document.getElementById("playfield");
var indexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];


for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var vak1 = document.createElement("span");
    var kaart1 = document.createElement("img");
    var path1 = "img/kaart" + indexes[i] + ".png";
    var klasse1 = "img" + indexes[i];
    //kaart1.setAttribute("src", "img/achterkant.png");
    kaart1.setAttribute("class", klasse1);
    kaart1.setAttribute("data-img", path1);
    kaart1.setAttribute("height", "150");
    kaart1.setAttribute("width", "150");
    kaart1.setAttribute("data-turned","false");
    vak1.appendChild(kaart1)
    playfield.appendChild(vak1);
 }
```

Append to the first and then add that to the playfield.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the created `<img>` as a child to `#playfield`.  If you want it in a `<span>`, you'll have to add it to the `<span>` and **then** add that `<span>` to `#playfield`.